# The List of figures contents overlap the title with the parskip package

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, parskip, vertical-spacing

I'm making a report and I'm trying to add the list of tables and figures to it. The list of tables renders completely fine, but the list of figures ends up looking like this, and I'm not quite sure why. I've also searched and not found anything relevant to solve this issue.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{itemsep=1pt, parsep=4pt}

\linespread{1.25}
\setlength{\parskip}{2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

    \newpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents

    \newpage
    \listoffigures

    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \section{Work done so far}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \caption{This is first figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,angle=90,origin=c]{new-request.png}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \caption{This is second figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{wireframe.png}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: list of figures]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! It is always suggested to provide an [mwe](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for others to start with.

Comment: Okay @muzimuzhiZ, I'll try and reformat that code into one single example.

Comment: Hi! Tom from Overleaf support here. Note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag (as this is not directly Overleaf-related) and did some other minor changes. To me this looks like a bug in the `parskip` package, I'll try to raise it with someone who can confirm whether it's a bug and what's going on. Btw, a more minimal example is this one: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xtrtqxyvjmtc

Comment: So after [some discussion with LaTeX devs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54409593#54409593), this really looks like a bug. I reported it at https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex/issues/12

Comment: Thanks @yo'. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Arvind No worries, it's not your fault :-)

Comment: @yo' can you post that as an answer so that I can mark it and then close out this question? Might be helpful for anyone else who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the `parskip` package: https://github.com/FrankMittelbach/fmitex/issues/12

As one of possible workarounds, you can undo the wrong negative space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skip=20pt]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{\vspace*{20pt}}

\newpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is first figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{This is second figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When using `tocloft`, I was getting extra space due to `tocloft`'s `\cftbeforefigskip`. Subtracting `\cftbeforefigskip`'s length from the `20pt` corrected it.